# How to change the iOS single quote in SQL?

Tags: sql

My Device Name : Tamilmani,' iPhone

Device OS : iOS 11.4.1

In SQL database device name will save as Tamilmani‚Äôs iPhone

single quote will change it as some special characters. How to avoid this SQL database ?

Anyone could you please help on this?

Thanks
Tamilmani Mohan

Comment: What is the type of the column? It probably should be `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use double single quote `''`to escaped and solve it.

```
Tamilmani,'' iPhone
```

Here is a simple

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   DeviceName varchar(50),
   DeviceOS  varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Tamilmani,'' iPhone','iOS 11.4.1');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77e6e4/1/0)**:

```
|         DeviceName |   DeviceOS |
|--------------------|------------|
| Tamilmani,' iPhone | iOS 11.4.1 |
```